# Creating a library for pygame and my global variables are not working

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple library to simplify certain `pygame` functions and other things. When I try to use my function that sets `RGB` variables it says it's not defined.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matthew.shapiro\Desktop\Files_for_code_S2\librarytest.py", line 7, in <module>
    fill(BLACK)
NameError: name 'BLACK' is not defined
```

```py
#library
import pygame
import math
def autoscreen(a,b):
    global size
    global screen
    size = (500,500)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
def basicRGB():
    global BLACK
    BLACK = (   0,   0,   0)
    global WHITE
    WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
    global GREEN
    GREEN = (   0, 255,   0)
    global RED
    RED = ( 255,   0,   0)
    global BLUE
    BLUE = (   0,   0, 255)
def setPI():
    global PI
    PI = 3.141592653
def flip():
    pygame.display.flip()
def fps(c):
    global clock
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    clock.tick(c)
def fill(e):
    screen.fill(e)


#librarytest
import pygame
from easypygame import*
autoscreen(500,500)
fps(60)
flip()
basicRGB()
fill(BLACK)
```

Comment: This works for me (when I set `fill = lambda color: print(color)`). What version of Python are you using? Although in practice, I would just define all of your global color variables in the global scope instead of in a function

Comment: You mention trying to create a library, are you importing this code to run it in another file? Written the way it is it appears to work fine for me.

Comment: I am importing it from another file

Comment: Could you post a sample from both files that will recreate your error? Ideally I would be able to copy paste what you post and immediately recreate the error on my machine.  Your current code does not let me do this.

Comment: Edited it to add all of both files

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a class, instead of global, use self.BLACK instead. If is it is not, use a dictionary, such as this:

```
def basicRGB():
    dictionary={}
    dictionary.update({'BLACK':(   0,   0,   0)})
    return dictionary

def fill(dictionary, e):
    screen.fill(dictionary[e])
```

for and example, go to [this repl.it program that I made using this.](https://repl.it/repls/BuoyantShoddyInstitute)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest importing a bit differently, instead of the line `from easypygame import*`, use: `import easypygame as ep` or something.  Global variables in Python are really only module wide, which is why you get your error, there is no `BLACK` in your librarytest file.  By importing this new way you can access individual parts of the new module with: `ep.BLACK` from outside of your module.  This will let you continue to update your variables from inside `pyeasygame` and access them from outside.